# QGIS 3.8.2: Gdalwmscache folder being created on save

Tags: qgis-3

I have a 'home' project which includes all my standard layers I use frequently, including Vector, Raster and WMS layers.

When I save this project I get a folder written to my Desktop called 'Gdalwmscache' which contains a large number of sub-folders/ files.
Is there a way of either suppressing the creation of this folder, or changing its default write location as it clutters up my desktop?

It deletes easily enough after close and doesn't appear to effect the load time when I restart the project.